# Django Can't load Json in POST request body if more than 1 parameter is passed in URL

Tags: python, django

I have a views.py with an endpoint like this:

```
def endpoint(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        body = request.body.decode('utf-8')
        body = json.loads(body)
        param1 = request.GET.get('param1','default1')
        param2 = request.GET.get('param2','default2')
```

My urls.py have this urlpattern:

```
url(r'^endpoint$', views.endpoint, name="endpoint")
```

The problem I have is that if I send requests in one of the following ways it works fine:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/endpoint -d @data.json

curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/endpoint?param1=val1 -d @data.json

curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/endpoint?param2=val2 -d @data.json
```

But if I send a request with both parameters:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/endpoint?param1=val1&param2=val2 -d @data.json
```

I get the exception:

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char
>   0)

Why I get JSONDecodeError when having multiple parameters? Is it because it's a POST request?

EDIT: I have to use a file **data.json** because de body of the request is quite big.

I also tried with a smaller json

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/endpoint?param1=val1&param2=val2 -d "{"a": "b"}"
```

To debug I inserted this on the beginning of the code:

```
print("request body:")
print(request.body)
```

I get this in the terminal:

> request body: 
>   b''

It seems Django don't even receive the request body

Comment: what's `@data.json`?

Comment: Edit your question to show what the request body looks like when you send two parameters.

Comment: in the command line the `&` means run command in background, try to put url in the double quotes: `"http://localhost:8000/endpoint?param1=val1&param2=val2"`

Comment: Thanks @Bear Brown. If you add your comment as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Why don’t you use django rest framework serialzers ability and api views that covers all of the json parsing and field validations, etc...

Comment: @misraX I come from a Spring Boot background and it indeed have this feature. Do you have by chance a recommended guide or other resource that teaches how to combine Serializers with api_views? I read [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view) but it tells only about HTTP methods, e.g. `@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the command line the `&` means run command in background, try to put url in the double quotes: `"http://localhost:8000/endpoint?param1=val1&param2=val2"`

`curl -X POST "http://localhost:8000/endpoint?param1=val1&param2=val2" -d @data.json`